# Prove that $\lim_{s \to \infty} \sum_{x=1}^{2s} (-1)^x\sum_{n=1}^{x}\frac{1}{n!}=\cosh (1) -1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, hyperbolic-functions

How can we prove that $$\lim_{s \to \infty} \sum_{x=1}^{2s} (-1)^x\sum_{n=1}^{x}\frac{1}{n!}=\cosh (1) -1$$

It seems like this is some kind of telescopic series, but I don't know how to find the limit of this sum. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: write $\cosh(x)$ using exponentials. Then try to manipulate the expression using the series for $e^x$

Comment: When you say manipulate the expression, do you mean to expand $e^x$ into its Taylor series?

Comment: Yes I mean that, and in the end evaluate at $x = 1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:**

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{x=1}^{2s}(-1)^x \sum_{n=1}^x\frac1{n!}&=\sum_{x=1}^s\left(-\sum_{n=1}^{2x-1}\frac1{n!}+\sum_{n=1}^{2x}\frac1{n!}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{x=1}^s\frac1{(2x)!}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Ah and $\cosh (1) = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2x)!}$. That solves it!
+1

Comment: Actually, the answer is $\cosh(1)-1$.

Comment: That's weird Mathematica seems to be giving me $\cosh (1)$

Comment: The lower limit here is $1$.  If you sum from $0$, then $\cosh(1)$ is the result.

Comment: Ah yes you are right

Comment: So, you have it now?

Comment: I understand now. Thank you sir!

Comment: Whoah. Um, why can we make the first expansion?

Comment: @math4ever Pleased to hear.  You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish Those are paired, even and odd, terms of the outer sum.

Answer (score -1):

$$\cosh(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}\Rightarrow \cosh(1)=\frac{e+e^{-1}}{2}$$

---

$$S=\sum_{x=1}^{2s}(-1)^x\sum_{n=1}^x\frac{1}{n!}$$
$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}\Rightarrow \cosh(1)=\frac 12\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1^n+(-1)^n}{n!}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left[1+(-1)^n\right]1^n}{n!}$$
now since for even odd n the terms will equal zero, we want:
$$\cosh(1)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1^{2n}}{(2n)!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n)!}$$
going back to $S$ now we have:
$$S=\sum_{x=1}^{2s}(-1)^x\sum_{n=1}^x\frac{1}{n!}=-\left(\frac 1{1!}\right)+\left(\frac 1{1!}+\frac 1{2!}\right)-\left(\frac 1{1!}+\frac 1{2!}+\frac 1{3!}\right)+...$$
and if you look at which terms you will cancel you notice that we are left with:
$$S=\sum_{x=1}^s\frac 1{(2x)!}$$
Now we are simply left with:
$$\lim_{s\to\infty}S_s=\cosh(1)$$

Comment: Your conclusion is incorrect.  $S_n\to \cosh(1)-1\ne \cosh(1)$.